# Error while configuration new SSL certificate on LDAP server and client

Tags: security, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, https

My last SSL certificate expired yesterday and which was configured on my LDAP server, so I purchased a new SSL key activated it and again tried to configure but still it showing the same error. First I tried `ldapsearch -d 33 -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -b "dc=example,dc=com"  -D "cn=manager,ou=Internal,dc=example,dc=com" -w Zsi9olp4rf8jWi6bmD`
to connect with server then output was

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ldap.example.com)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://ldap.example.com:636/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP ldap.example.com:636
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.2.0.102:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
TLS: certdb config: configDir='/etc/openldap/cacerts' tokenDescription='ldap(0)' certPrefix='' keyPrefix='' flags=readOnly
TLS: using moznss security dir /etc/openldap/cacerts prefix .
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/openldap/cacerts/f96879fa.1.
**TLS: certificate [CN=*.example.com,OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard,OU=Domain Control Validated] is not valid - error -8181:Peer's Certificate has expired..**
TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 21 - moznss error -8174
TLS: can't connect: TLS error -8174:security library: bad database..
ldap_err2string
**ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)**
```

So I copied new keys to LDAP server's `/etc/openldap/cacerts/cert.pem` file
but there is an another file `/etc/openldap/cacerts/key.pem`. Now I'm confused about which file I should add the keys to.

At Clients there are a lot of files in cacerts folder. Please check the attached photos for files.

[image: Client cacerts file]

[image: server cacerts file]

Please suggest where I need to add new ssl key for proper configuration.

Answer (score 1):

SSL requires both a private key and a public key.  For reasons beyond the scope of this answer, your public key is sent to a Certificate Authority (or CA) in your Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and included in the certificate that comes back to you.

A server needs both the private and public key (almost always wrapped in a certificate) to work.  That's why you see two files.

If you generated your new certificate with the same private key, you should be able to replace just the certificate.  Most online instructions for creating a CSR also generate a new private key (in the same folder).  In that case, you'll need to find and use that private key in conjunction with your certificate.